# Flutter: add counter to paginationt list reruned

Tags: arrays, laravel, flutter, controller

### Edited :

I have this controller to get some user data

```
{
    $predects = Predect::groupBy('user_id')->selectRaw(' user_id ,SUM(point) as points')->orderBy('points','desc')->get();
        $counter=0;
        foreach($predects as $predect){
            $counter++;
            $predect->counter=$counter;
            $predect->username=$predect->User->username;
            unset($predect->User);
        }
        $result=$predects->where('username',$user);
        return $result;
}
```

the result is something like this :

```
{
  "4": {
    "user_id": 10,
    "points": "8",
    "counter": 2,
    "username": "sar"
  }
}
```

How can I remove 4 from data to be like this:

```
[
  {
    "user_id": 9,
    "points": "15",
    "counter": 1,
    "username": "sarmed"
  }
]
```

Comment: Do you need to calculate/do something with that value or is it just for presentational purpose? Does the counter really have to be part of a model? If it's for presentation only use `<ol>`s

Comment: @brombeer yes , I will need it for determine the page contain specified user

Comment: Not sure how a counter helps "_determine the page contain specified user_", but the Paginator already contains all data you need to calculate an items "counter". It contains `"per_page": X` and `"current_page": Y`, I think that would be all you need to get a continous counter for any item. [Converting Results To JSON](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/pagination#converting-results-to-json). Edit: the paginator even has `"from": X` and `"to": Y` fields that could be used

Comment: @brombeer ok thanks I'll try to do something in frontend

Comment: @brombeer can I change my question here ?

Comment: You can [edit] your question and update it, yes, as long as it stays on-topic. Don't change it to a different question/topic. Ask a new question for that